# PHP countdown to event and updates when event has passed

Tags: php, time, countdown

I have a Jquery countdown until a weekly event. The event is at 7:00 pm US Central time every sunday. I generate the countdown in php. I am looking for a way to set the countdown to display the next event a week later an hour after the current event.

Example:

The event is every Sunday at 7:00 PM CST and last an hour.

If you look at the site at 6:00 PM on Sunday, it should start the countdown for an hour. (00:01:00:00)
If you look at the site at 7:00 PM - 8:00 PM on Sunday, it will show 0. (00:00:00:00)
If you look at the event at 9:00 PM on Sunday, it will show 6days 22hrs 0min 0sec (06:22:00:00)

I have the code to show the countdown for a date and time I enter, but I want this to happen without changing the code every week.

```
<?php 
        $rem = strtotime('2012-09-02 19:00:00') - time();
        $day1 = floor($rem / 86400);
        $hr1  = floor(($rem % 86400) / 3600);
        $min1 = floor(($rem % 3600) / 60);
        $sec1 = ($rem % 60);
        $day = sprintf('%02d',$day1);
        $hr = sprintf('%02d',$hr1);
        $min = sprintf('%02d',$min1);
        $sec = sprintf('%02d',$sec1);
        echo "$day:";
        echo "$hr:";
        echo "$min:";
        echo "$sec"; ?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Trust me when I tell you this: `DateTime` objects will save you a WHOLE lot of headache.

Comment: I realize that the code I have is not the best way to do it, but it works for now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php function to convert Unix timestamp into minutes or hours or days like digg?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059603/php-function-to-convert-unix-timestamp-into-minutes-or-hours-or-days-like-digg)

Comment: @Jaret That's a bad programming attitude, especially when the alternative given is in addition easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = new DateTime("Next Sunday 7:00 PM", new DateTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
$diff = $time->diff(new DateTime("now"));
echo $diff->format("%D:%H:%I:%S");
```

Change the **[timezone](http://il.php.net/timezones)** according to what fits you best. Don't rely on UTC/CST/WHATEVER, give a proper location so that your times are accurate.

Comment: For some reason it is displaying object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-09-09 19:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(15) "America/Chicago" } 07:03:35:28 instead of just 07:03:35:28